# Functions Query string parameter on custom post type hides my wordpress nav menu

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have the following code in my functions.php file which allows me to query posts in my custom post type named 'jobs' and filter them where an ACF field named 'bracket' matches a certain value. It works fine, but when the page loads and i see the url appended such as '/jobs/?bracket=20-30' my wordpress navigation menu items aren't present on the page. I can't understand whats wrong:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts', 10, 1);

function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) 
{

// bail early if is in admin
if( is_admin() ) 
{
    return;
}

// get meta query
$meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');

// initialize meta query as empty array if not set
if ( ! is_array( $meta_query ) ) {
    $meta_query = array();
}
    
// continue if not found in url
if( isset($_GET[ 'bracket' ]) ) 
{
    // append meta query
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'       => 'bracket',
        'value'     => $_GET['bracket'],
        'compare'   => '=',
    );
}
    
// update meta query
$query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);

return;
}
```

Anybody got any ideas how to fix this?